# Do Cameroonian citizens need visas to transit through Suvarnabhumi airport (Bangkok)?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, luggage, bangkok, cameroonian-citizens

We made a single online booking from Shanghai to Yaounde, Cameroon.
The connecting flight to Thailand is with Thai Airways TG665, which arrives at 9:15pm in Bangkok. We catch the next flight at 1am with Kenya Airways.

At Bangkok we need to take our luggage once we arrive, then check in again to the next flight.

Normally there is no transit visa required for international passengers transiting through Bangkok.

Since we need to get our luggage first, before checking in to the next flight, will we go through immigration? If yes, do we need any visas as Cameroon passport holders?
Also, is the 3 hours transit time enough for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To collect and re-check tour baggage you will not stay in the transit area and therefore will enter Thailand and are not eligible to transit without  a visa. You should apply for a transit visa.

As per TIMATIC:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Passengers transiting through Bangkok (BKK) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 12 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

As you don’t stay in the transit area this doesn’t apply to you. You aren’t visa free to enter Thailand therefore you need a visa.

3 hours is a bit tight but the connection time should be fine.

Comment: thank you very much for that clarification. please per your advise should i cancel this ticket and book another one or the 3 hrs will be enough from your experience?

Comment: @MOMO I’ve never been at the airport, but if there is no cancellation fee I recommend you could book another one. If it’s too complicated it’s a bit risky but doable

Comment: thank you i think i will try and change them. by the way if we decide to travel without any luggage could we get the boarding pass at the transit area ?